# Orden del htaccess que no se ejecuta

Tags: .htaccess

Después de pelearme un poco he conseguido avanzar en el htaccess que ayer puse por aquí, y ha quedado tal que así:

```
# inicio del motor 

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase / 

# evitamos que se entienda como amigable una url que existe como carpeta o como fichero

      RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

# añade la contrabarra al final de todas las url si no la lleva 

      RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301]  

# convertimos las url 

      RewriteRule ^(.*)$          buscarFicha.php?slug=$1 
      RewriteRule ^contacto$      contacto.php
```

Ahora me encuentro con que el rewriterule del contacto no se ejecuta nunca, poniendo `www.miweb.com/contacto` o ponga lo que ponga, se va a `buscarFicha.php`.

Probé a ponerle el flag `[L]` a ambas instrucciones, también a ponerlas en orden inverso, para que evalúe primero si he puesto contacto, y si no, que siga con el resto de instrucciones, pero ninguna me ha dado resultado.